# Pipe an ssh candump to own can-interface

Tags: python, shell, ssh, pipe, can-bus

I am trying to pipe a remote ssh candump to my local computer and send it to my own (virtual) can-interface.

My current (working) solution is to execute in one terminal:
`ssh user@remote-host 'candump can0' > log.log`

And after several (mill)-seconds in a different terminal:
`canplayer -I log.log vcan0=can0`

Where vcan0 is the local interface I set up on my computer.

This seems to be a quite bumpy solution but I could not get others ones to work (gnome-terminal tabs, using '&' on the first command to combine it with the second, and several others).

The perfect solution would be to execute an .sh script which does the described functionality. Any suggestions or ideas? A python script would be fine for me as well.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I have limited functionalities on the remote-host so I cannot install new packages and the list of packages is reduced to a minimum.